# how can clear only cache of application not other data (sharedpreference)

Tags: android

I am working on app and saved data in sharedpreference and cache, I want clear only cache of application not sharedpreference data. How can I do it? It's my code

```
public void clearApplicationData(Context context) 
{
    File cache = context.getCacheDir();
    File appDir = new File(cache.getParent());
    if (appDir.exists()) {
        String[] children = appDir.list();
        for (String s : children) {
            if (!s.equals("lib")) {
                deleteDir(new File(appDir, s));Log.i("TAG", "**************** File /data/data/APP_PACKAGE/" + s + " DELETED *******************");
            }
        }
    }     public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
        if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
           String[] children = dir.list();
           for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
               System.out.println("Directory not null");
              boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
              if (!success) {
                 return false;
              }
           }
        }

        // The directory is now empty so delete it
        return dir.delete();
     }
```

Comment: Use Java file I/O to delete files in "cache", by which I assume that you mean `getCacheDir()` and `getExternalCacheDir()`.

Comment: I used getCacheDir() . but it cleared all data which saved in application local memory.

Comment: The `getCacheDir()` directory does not hold all data "which saved in application local memory". In particular, it does not hold `SharedPreferences`, at least not by default.

Comment: it's working well but when i run application it's clear all the data of local memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when i run application it's clear all the data of local memory

That is because of this line:

```
File appDir = new File(cache.getParent());
```

Get rid of it. Get rid of every reference to `appDir`.

If you want to delete `getCacheDir()`, then **delete `getCacheDir()`**, not other things, like the `getParent()` of `getCacheDir()`.

Comment: Thank you so much it was a great help to me.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the Cache Directory

```
public static void deleteCache(Context context) {
try {
    File dir = context.getCacheDir();
    if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
        deleteDir(dir);
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {}
}

public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
    String[] children = dir.list();
    for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
        if (!success) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
return dir.delete();
}
```

you need permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE"/>
```